# Detaching Intentity Claims from the Identity

Tags: wif

I'm working against the framework's Identity Claims Foundation. Currently I am gaining access to pertinent claims via the framework's User.Identity object `(var a = User.Identity.Name)`.

What I'd like to implement is access to the same claim info using only the `UserId` field - In other words, i have an `Order` entity, *it* has a `UserId` property - i want to avoid loading the `User.Identity` object because it's different than the current user. Instead, it's gained by the `UserId` property.

1) Is this something that i *should* want, or is it just me digging more rabbit holes?
2) If yes, how best to pattern?